# Running weka through C#

Tags: c#, java, weka

I am running weka through C# code, and the code for this is given below.

```
 using System;

 class MainClass
 {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Hello Java, from C#!");
     classifyTest();
  }

  const int percentSplit = 66;
  public static void classifyTest()
  {
     try
     {
         weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("iris.arff"));
         insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1);

         weka.classifiers.Classifier cl = new weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
         Console.WriteLine("Performing " + percentSplit + "% split evaluation.");

         //randomize the order of the instances in the dataset.
                     weka.filters.Filter myRandom = new weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.Randomize();
         myRandom.setInputFormat(insts);
                     insts = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(insts, myRandom);

         int trainSize = insts.numInstances() * percentSplit / 100;
         int testSize = insts.numInstances() - trainSize;
         weka.core.Instances train = new weka.core.Instances(insts, 0, trainSize);

         cl.buildClassifier(train);
         int numCorrect = 0;
         for (int i = trainSize; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
         {
             weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
             double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
             if (predictedClass = insts.instance(i).classValue())
                 numCorrect++;
         }
         Console.WriteLine(numCorrect + " out of " + testSize + " correct (" +
                    (double)((double)numCorrect / (double)testSize * 100.0) + "%)");
     }
     catch (java.lang.Exception ex)
     {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

 }
 //end of file Main.cs
```

I have added Weka.dll and ikvm.JDK.Core.dll file.
But I get this error when i try to run it

the type initializer for 'java.io.file' threw an exception

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you did not add all the references required, You have to add all the dll files that starts with  ikvm.OpenJDK and the file IKVM.Runtime.dll also make sure that you converted the weka.jar to weka.dll using IKVM

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you add Refrences for IKVM.Runtime.dll and IKVM.Runtime.JNI.dll

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify a path for `"iris.arff"`, probably the file is not located in the startup directory of your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using weka.classifiers.meta;
using weka.classifiers.functions;
using weka.core;
using java.io;
using weka.clusterers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
```

I tested this script using the above libraries as followes and got a double to bool error on :

```
     if (predictedClass = insts.instance(i).classValue())
         numCorrect++;
```

but otherwise it worked fine once the path ot iris.arff was set. I hope this helps.